# add two multidimensional array and add all items of them in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays and want to join them with all the items.
it can be re-index again wont be any issue.

I have create these array in a foreach loop and use this for batch insert query.

here is the array, I want to add both of them

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question_def_id] => 1
                    [description] => 3
                    [description_hindi] => 3
                    [correct] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [question_def_id] => 1
                    [description] => 4
                    [description_hindi] => 4
                    [correct] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [question_def_id] => 1
                    [description] => 5
                    [description_hindi] => 5
                    [correct] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [question_def_id] => 1
                    [description] => 6
                    [description_hindi] => 6
                    [correct] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: I have solve this problem using array_push in the loop and drop this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Join two  multidimensional array

```
$test_array1 = array(array('question_def_id'=>1,'description'=>2),    array('question_def_id'=>3,'description'=>4));
$test_array2 = array(array('question_def_id'=>5,'description'=>6), array('question_def_id'=>7,'description'=>8));
 $C = array_merge($test_array1, $test_array2);
            print_r($C);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP `array_merge_recursive` function to merge both arrays into one.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

E.g

```
<?php
  $ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
  $ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
  $result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
  print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: array_merge_recursive can not used like this: 
$result = array_merge_recursive($result, $ar2);

What is I want to use this way: $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $ar2);